# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always True

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, web-config

Could someone tell me how to handle the authentication mode @asp.net mvc 3 ?
My webconfig has no entry for the tag authentication bcause i dont know which mode is suiteable!

refering to the title:

i'd like to hide some navigations buttons @View, and i tried it with "if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)" but thats always true,even if i'm not logged in (on the Website!)

someone an idea?

best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have remove the `<authentication>` tag from your web.config it means that you are allowing anonymous access to your site. So anyone is considered as authenticated. That's why `IsAuthenticated` is always `true`.

You will need to enable some sort of authentication that you want to use. For example if you want to use [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

So the first thing you will have to decide is how do you intend to manage users and roles. Where do you intend to store them. Once you have decided this it is pretty easy to use either the built-in Membership and Role providers or write custom ones if they don't fit your needs.

I would recommend you start here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs

Comment: No, don't use `<allow>` and `<deny>` tags in ASP.NET MVC. Authorization is controlled by decorating controllers/actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: but i've got a Link for LogOn and LogOff, has it got an attribute for the opposit of Authorize ? if(Authorize) -> LogOff, If (!Authorize) -> LogOn

Comment: No, there isn't. You need to decorate only controller actions that require authorization with the Authorize attribute. Or if you decorate the controller with this attribute all actions will require authorization. Another possibility is to put the action that doesn't require authorization in a different controller.

Comment: Actually, you can decorate your controller class with [Authorize] and then decorate any actions that should allow anonymous access with [AllowAnonymous]. I'd only do that if most of your actions require authorization. If most should allow anonymous then decorate the others with [Authorize].

Comment: For me it is returning `True` instead of `true`.